# Convert date to string for a locale in Windows

Tags: windows, string, date, crt

This might be a simple one but I can't seem to find an easy solution. I need to format a date as a string to be represented in a full form for a locale. Example:

May 28, 2011 (for US locale)

_strftime_l(_T("%#x")) can do a similar thing but it adds a weekday up front, that I don't need.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what this means?

Comment: You know what, I'm amazed that some people actually care about a nonsense like that )) I thought that the whole point is in helping someone out and not getting a check mark checked....

Answer (score 0):

GetDateFormat and GetTimeFormat (or the Ex versions for Vista and up).

Comment: I looked all over the GetDateFormat API's description and I can't see how I can get the format that I described above?

Comment: You can specify some flags in combination with using the current user's locale to get general date formats (short date, long date).  If you want full control over the format then you can specify your own format string.

Comment: What flags would you specify to produce the format that I need? Again:
May 28, 2011 (for US locale)

Comment: The are flags for short and long formats, but if you want a specific format just use an appropriate format string: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317787%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: OK, say, I call GetDateFormat API and get the following for US locale: "dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy". What I need is everything except the dddd part. So, say, I can remove dddd, but what shall I do with the comma there? And if it's not a comma but something else? So, is it what you're saying, because I'm not really following it....

Comment: Oh, are you saying you want a locale-specific string without the day of the week part?  I don't think there is a generic way to do that; you can either do the long date or the short date.  I was saying to use your own format string (e.g. "MMMM dd, yyyy"), but that would not obey locale settings.